# How can I install Sierra on my Mac Pro Tower early 2008?

Tags: macos, install, mac-pro

I would just like to install Sierra on my unsupported Mac Pro Tower early 2008. I know it is not supported, but as the machine itself is no longer supported by Apple, I don't really care.

I have tried the Sierra patch tool from DosDude. However, the installer disk it creates hangs during boot with the error:

```
Can't get kexts port.
com.apple.bsd.dirhelper.489 Warning: Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.bsd.com
```

Even after exchanging emails with DosDude, we weren't able to resolve the problem.

Is there another way to go about this? What does the Sierra installer check to know whether the machine is supported? If I were to find a way around this, is there some hardware-related reason why Sierra wouldn't run on this machine? E.g. ROM? According to the MacTracker app, my tower has a Intel Xeon 5400 series ("Harpertown") processor. The Boot ROM and SMC versions are:
 Boot ROM Version:  MP31.006C.B05
 SMC Version (system):  1.25f4

I have a MacBook Air and I could afford to buy a new Mac. It's just that, damn it, I'm attached this old tower. It has run for years and is still very fast (especially with its new SSD drives). I could continue with El Capitan, but Sierra has many fixes to bugs I'm currently living with, plus improvements to many Apple apps that I would like to enjoy.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but I'll suggest it out of my own curiosity. Have you tried starting your Mac Pro Tower in Target Disk Mode and connecting to it from another Mac to try installing macOS Sierra? That is, using a Mac capable of running macOS Sierra to install the OS onto your Mac Pro as though it were the internal hard drive? Obviously, you may need to use a cable and/or adapter, and perhaps your MacBook Air (you haven't specified the model) won't be suitable. Another thing I'd do is try older versions of the macOS Sierra Patcher Tool to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: http://lowendmac.com/2016/macos-sierra/

Comment: Both excellent suggestions that I will try

Comment: @Monomeeth even if you managed to instal through target disk mode, you'd need to patch the installation or the computer would refuse to boot from it